# Mongo DB + group by with last field data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have sample json data in collections.

Sample data:

```
[{
    "_id" : 1,
    "username" : "abcd",
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2016-06-03T08:52:32.434Z")
},
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "username" : "abcd",
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2016-05-03T09:52:32.434Z")
},
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "username" : "abcd",
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2016-04-03T10:52:32.434Z")
},
{
    "_id" : 4,
    "username" : "xyz",
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2016-03-03T10:52:32.434Z")
},{
    "_id" : 5,
    "username" : "xyz",
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2016-02-03T10:52:32.434Z")
},{
    "_id" : 6,
    "username" : "zzz",
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2016-01-03T10:52:32.434Z")
}]
```

This data I need to retrieve data for following condtions.

1. Group by username.
2. username not equal "zzz"
3. Order by date desc order.
4. need date field also (which have lastest/last record).
5. get total count.

Expecting output:

```
[{
    "username" : "abcd",
    "createdDate" : "2016-06-03T08:52:32.434Z",
        "total" : 3
},
{
    "username" : "xyz",
    "createdDate" : "2016-03-03T10:52:32.434Z",
        "total" : 2
}]
```

Query:

```
db.logs.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "username": { "$ne": "zzz" } }},

    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "username": "$username",
            "createdDate": "$createdDate"
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}])
```

Comment: What's your MongoDB version?

Comment: You probably want to change sample data to have different creation dates for the same user.

Comment: @chridam I am using version 3.2.4

Comment: @AlexBlex - pls suggest. i didn't get

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Didn't notice the month is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
    db.logs.aggregate([
   {
      "$match":{
         "username":{
            "$ne":"zzz"
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "$group":{
         _id:"$username",
         "count":{
            "$sum":1
         },
         date:{
            $max:"$createdDate"
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $project:{
         username:"$_id",
         total:"$count",
         createdDate:"$date"
      }
   }
])
```

output

```
  {
   "_id":"xyz",
   "username":"xyz",
   "total":2,
   "createdDate":   ISODate("2016-03-03T10:52:32.434   Z")
}{
   "_id":"abcd",
   "username":"abcd",
   "total":3,
   "createdDate":   ISODate("2016-06-03T08:52:32.434   Z")
}
```

try it online: [mongoplayground.net/p/3_-s2tUjPFi](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3_-s2tUjPFi)

Comment: Hi,sorry for late reply. i tried this query but getting error. I attached my code here https://jsfiddle.net/rajinikumarr/ewg4kze1/1/

Comment: @RSKMR well in the jsfiddle you used "db.activities.find()" instead of "db.activities.aggregate()" so of course it wont work... You can't use $match and $group in find queries, only in aggregation

Comment: oh sorry, I missed.